# developing a program without a gui

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create a program but need some help. I am quite new to coding and have tried to find answers online. I am having a menu when the program is opened and once an option is called (there are 6 options) it needs to print a table. so far I have,

```py
    def main ():
      choice = printMenu()
      print (choice)

    def printMenu ():
      print("Astronaut Mass Allowance Calculator")
      print("A: Display Program options")
      print("B: Display Destinations with Mass Multipliers")
      print("C: Display Weight allowances for astronauts")
      print("D: Calculate Personal Mass allowances")
      print("E: Calculate Average Available mass and weight")
      print("X: Exit")
      print("Enter A, B, C, D, E or X to proceed:")

    main()
```

Once a letter is input, how can I call the rest?

Comment: In print function have a switch case and create your respective table. Add break in each switch case option to prevent other options execution.

Comment: There is no switch case in python. You will have to implement if-elseif-else type code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want the User to look at the printed Menu and select one option. Then based on the user's input you want your program to act further. If this is what you expect then I would suggest remove the last print from Menu Options take make it part of "Input" and use it like this:

```
def main ():
      printMenu()
      ip = input("Enter A, B, C, D, E or X to proceed:")
      #do what you want with this option
      print("you entered: " + ip)

def printMenu ():
      print("Astronaut Mass Allowance Calculator")
      print("A: Display Program options")
      print("B: Display Destinations with Mass Multipliers")
      print("C: Display Weight allowances for astronauts")
      print("D: Calculate Personal Mass allowances")
      print("E: Calculate Average Available mass and weight")
      print("X: Exit")
      #Last line removed from here

main()
```

Comment: if the user selects A how can i get it to print the "print menu' again?

Comment: @vivace, Once you have the users input in your variable ip, you can then take your decision. For eg. you can check if ip == "A" then may be print the sub-menu option etc. This is your program flow now.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `printMenu` doesn't return anything. So `choice = printMenu()` is useless. You should use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) or [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) (depends on python version) to read user input and then use

```py
if choice == "A":
  displayProgramOptions()
elif choice == "B":
  // ...
else:
  print("Unknown option")
```

Or use `dict` that can map the string to function. I.e.

```py
funcs = {
  "A": displayProgramOptions,
  "B": displayDestinationsWithMassMultipliers,
  // ...
}

if choice in funcs:
  funcs[choice]()
else:
  print("Unknown option")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the response you might use the input() function. Do you need further help?

```
def main ():
  choice = printMenu()
  print (choice)
  # Do something here with the choice, as P.Dmitry suggests.

def printMenu ():
  print("Astronaut Mass Allowance Calculator")
  print("A: Display Program options")
  print("B: Display Destinations with Mass Multipliers")
  print("C: Display Weight allowances for astronauts")
  print("D: Calculate Personal Mass allowances")
  print("E: Calculate Average Available mass and weight")
  print("X: Exit")
  return input("Enter A, B, C, D, E or X to proceed:")

main()
```

Comment: if the user selects A how can i get it to print the "print menu' again?

Answer (score 0):

I'd break out the logic into separate functions so they can each output their own info:

```
  def A():
    print('A CODE HERE')
  def B():
    print('B CODE HERE')
  def C():
    print('C CODE HERE')
  def D():
    print('D CODE HERE')
  def E():
    print('E CODE HERE')
  def X():
    quit()

  def main():
    choice = printMenu()
    print('YOU CHOSE:', choice)
    if choice == 'A':
      A()
    elif choice == 'B':
      B()
    elif choice == 'C':
      C()
    elif choice == 'D':
      D()
    elif choice == 'E':
      E()
    elif choice == 'X':
      X()

  def printMenu():
    print("Astronaut Mass Allowance Calculator")
    print("A: Display Program options")
    print("B: Display Destinations with Mass Multipliers")
    print("C: Display Weight allowances for astronauts")
    print("D: Calculate Personal Mass allowances")
    print("E: Calculate Average Available mass and weight")
    print("X: Exit")
    # Collect input from the user.
    choice = input("Enter A, B, C, D, E or X to proceed: ")
    # Return the input.
    return choice.upper()

  while True: # Infinitely display the choice menu
    main()
```